# PowerShell: Parallel: Out-File: The process cannot access the file

Tags: powershell, shell-script

I have the following script that I run in PS 7.2.0-preview.1:

```
get-childitem *.* -File -recurse | foreach-object -parallel {$hashX=(get-filehash -algorithm sha256 $_); $hash=@{sha256=$hashX.Hash; path=$hashX.Path}; write-output "$($hash.path)`t$($hash.sha256)" >> d:\g-SATA-hash.txt} -throttle 8
```

However, when running the script, I often get the error,

```
Out-File: The process cannot access the file
```

Obviously, it occurs because two or more parallel processes are trying to write the same output file at the same time (it runs fine without `-Parallel`).

My question is, is there a way to tell the process to keep trying to write to the output file until successful instead of posting an error message and moving on. I imagine there is something in a try-catch solution but I am unfamiliar with try-catch and error posting in PowerShell.

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: There is an answer on SO that shows how to synchronize file writing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084566/write-to-a-file-with-multiple-jobs-in-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell differentiates between terminating and non-terminating errors.
Non-terminating errors don't get caught by `try {}`, so the solution depends
on the nature of the error.

For **terminating errors**, use:

```
try
{
...tested action...
}
catch
{
...catch action...
}
```

For more information see the article
[Handling errors with PowerShell try-catch command](http://techgenix.com/powershell-try-catch-command/).

For **non-terminating errors**, use rather the `-ErrorAction` parameter.

Error actions are described in depth in:

- [Handling Errors the PowerShell Way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/)
- [-ErrorAction and -ErrorVariable](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/erroraction-and-errorvariable/)

For correctly **serializing actions** so no conflict arises, use
[Mutexes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=net-5.0).

An [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084566/write-to-a-file-with-multiple-jobs-in-powershell) is:

```
$mutex = new-object System.Threading.Mutex $false,'SomeUniqueName'
...
nr = $WorkflowData['_Number']
$mutex.WaitOne() > $null
$nr >> C:\Configuration\nrFile.txt
$mutex.ReleaseMutex()
```

For more information see the article
[Using Mutexes to Write Data to the Same Logfile Across Processes With PowerShell](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/09/30/using-mutexes-to-write-data-to-the-same-logfile-across-processes-with-powershell/).